# Testing for python module by importing in a Makefile

Tags: python, makefile

I am trying to create a generate Makefile.  Is there a way to test whether a python module exists and then perform different actions in the Makefile based on that?

I have tried something like this

```
all:

ifeq (,$(@ python -c 'import somemodule'))                                                                                                                                                                                                          
echo "DEF MODULE = 1" > settings.pxi                                                                                                                                                                                                     
else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
echo "DEF MODULE = 0" > settings.pxi                                                                                                                                                                                                     
endif                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    python setup.py build_ext --build-lib . --build-temp build --pyrex-c-in-temp
```

however doing this does not produce any result.  Also if the module does not exist, python throws an error- how to store this information rather than simply crashing?

Comment: You'll need to try/catch the body of the python code to have python not explode on you I think. Does running that code by hand produce output?

Comment: What you've written here is not a valid makefile; if you try to run make with that you'll get an error (_missing separator_).  Makefiles are not shell scripts.

Comment: Edited to show actual makefile

Comment: I also can't seem to do a try/except block using python -c...

Answer (score 0):

Consider making use of Python's [imp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) module. Specifically, `imp.find_module` should be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I think this gives the same problem as testing an import using just 'import somemodule', because it will also throw an error when the module is not found.

Comment: You've noticed you can't use try/catch from command line, so you'll need a module for this, with a module name passed in as an argument. That's going to be a string, but you can't use `import` with a string. That's where `imp.find_module` becomes useful.

Comment: Since 3.4, imp has been deprecated, so try https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html instead.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap everything in bash -c “cmd” works for me.

```
python_mod := $(shell bash -c "echo -e 'try:\n  import toml\n  print(\"good\")\nexcept ImportError:\n  print(\"bad\")' | python3 -")
ifeq "$(python_mod)" "error"
  $(error "python module is not installed")
endif
```